# IdentityModel OIDC Client Log Out

Tags: native, identity, logout, identityserver4, openid-connect

I've a native Windows Client application which is authenticating user against Identity Server. Login Works fine. However, I'm not able to sign out the user.

[Here is the link of the source code that I am using](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples/tree/master/WinFormsWebView)

I tried logoutAsync method with no luck. Once user is signed in, whenever I start the application and click login it automatically sign the user in.

Comment: In the sample you provided code inside LogoutButton_Click is commented out...

Answer (score -1):

In the sample you provided code inside LogoutButton_Click is commented out.

```
private async void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // await _oidcClient.LogoutAsync(trySilent: Silent.Checked);
    // AccessTokenDisplay.Clear();
    // OtherDataDisplay.Clear();
}
```